# Java compareto method beginner

Tags: java, compareto

While Comparable is supposed to capture the natural ordering for a class, it's possible to imagine unnatural orderings as well. So: in the box provided below, reimplement the compareTo() method so that one Infant is less than another, if the length of his or her name is less than the other.

```
public class Infant implements Comparable {

    private  String name;
    private int age;  // in months

    public Infant(String who, int months) {
        name = who;
        age = months;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void anotherMonth() {
        age = age + 1;
    }
```

This is what I have but I don't understand

```
    public int compareTo(Object other) {
        String b = ((Infant)other).getName();
        String a = this.name;
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
```

Comment: The short answer is yes...

Comment: how would I write the compareTo method for it to satisfy the question?

Comment: @user3002924 Compare the length of the strings, instead of the strings?

Answer (score 2):

`compareTo` allows you to define the result of how two objects compare to each other...

So, for your example you could use...

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {
    String b = ((Infant)other).getName();
    String a = this.name;
    return(a.length() - b.length());
}
```

Generally speaking, I would, personally, create "purpose" built `Comparable`s that allow you to change the default behaviour as required.

So you could define a `ByNameLengthComparable` and/or `ByAgeComparable` that could be past to things like `Arrays#sort` and `Collections#sort` for example...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want two orderings--the natural ordering and an alternative ordering. This is what `Comparable` and `Comparator` are for.

Now it is entirely up to you which is which, but let's just say I decide I want the natural order for an `Infant` to be by age and the alternate order to be by length of name.

Then you could do this utilizing generics:

```
public class Infant implements Comparable<Infant> {
//Stuff

  public int compareTo(Infant other) {
    return new Integer(age).compareTo(other.age);
    //or you can of course do the primitive comparisons but I'm lazy
    //and don't hate autoboxing
  }    
}
```

And then you could *also* do this:

```
public class InfantNameLengthComparator implements Comparator<Infant> {
  int compare(Infant first, Infant second) {
    return new Integer(first.getName().length()).compareTo(second.getName().length());
  }
}
```

And then you can sort in two ways:

`Collections.sort(listOfInfants);` by age--the default, natural ordering

`Collections.sort(listOfInfants, new InfantNameLengthComparator());` by length of name

You can even add other `Comparator`s to do other alternative orderings like alphabetically by name while always preserving the natural order by age.

So you can use both `Comparable` and `Comparator` to provide both natural order and alternate order.

If you like, you can check out a [tutorial](http://www.vidyasource.com/tutorial/Programming/Java/2013/10/27/comparison-shopping) we recently did on this exact subject.

Hope this helps.